# Extract string part in Javascript / Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, simple-form, cocoon-gem

I'm using cocoon gem to add dynamic nested forms for the working hours.

The Cocoon returns an open_time and close_time input.

```
id = merchant_working_hours_attributes_ID_open_time
id = merchant_working_hours_attributes_ID_close_time
```

At the css the close_time input is defined as display:none and my idea is just display if the open_time input is marked not nil.

But for that I need extract the ID from the open_time input and add a css style to the close_time input according that ID.

How can achieve that with javascript / Jquery? Any other form to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question says that you've a string and you wanna extract the ID of respective element to perform style.

**Use [split()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)**

```
var string = merchant_working_hours_attributes_ID_open_time;

var parts = string.split("_"); //You will have the ID at 4th parts[4]
```

Based on the extracted ID, you can use `show()` and `hide()`.

Example

```
if($('#opentimeID').val() != '')
{
  $('#opentimeID').show();
}
```

**Use [substring()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp)**

```
string.substring(start,end)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be relatively simple. My assumption is that, by default, the "close time" field isn't showing. But, when you start to put a value into the "open time" field, the "close time" field then shows up.

If that's the case, this should work for you.

**JavaScript**

```
const openTime = document.getElementById('merchant_working_hours_attributes_ID_open_time')
const closeTime = document.getElementById('merchant_working_hours_attributes_ID_close_time')
if (openTime.value.length > 0) {
  closeTime.style.display = 'block'
}
```